# Why won't my method read in every value from a file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
public static int getBoys(ArrayList<String> boysNames, Scanner s) throws IOException {
    // Getting boys file location
    System.out.println("Please enter the file name containing the the boys names.");
    String boyFileLocation = s.nextLine();

    // Opening the file containing the names of boys
    File boyFile = new File(boyFileLocation);
    Scanner BF = new Scanner(boyFile);
    int initialBoyCount = 0;
    int i = 0;
    boysNames.add(BF.nextLine());

    while (BF.hasNextLine()) {
        if (BF.nextLine().equals(boysNames.get(i))) {

        } else {
            boysNames.add(BF.nextLine());
            initialBoyCount++;
            i++;
            System.out.println(boysNames.get(i));
        }
    }

    return (initialBoyCount);
}
```

I am trying to read in from a file a list of names and add them to an array list. However there are duplicates of certain names and i am only suppoused to keep the unique ones (If if already exists don't add it again). However, I figured out that it is only giving me every other name. Starting with 2, and giving me the following errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at namesList.namesList.getBoys(namesList.java:53)
    at namesList.namesList.main(namesList.java:27)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the exception in this line

```
if (BF.nextLine().equals(boysNames.get(i)))
```

you read a line and if equation isn't `true` in else branch you call `BF.nextLine()` again. So sometimes you read line twice but you call `hasNextLine()` only once .

**Solution:** read line only one time before `if` statement.

Comment: I see what you're saying. So is there any way to reference what is in the file twice without moving the marker?

Comment: @M.Pestonit the solution: you should call `hasNextLine()` and `BF.nextLine()` only once. I've just changed my answer with the solution how it should be.

Comment: @Andriy try putting `String currentLine = BF.nextLine()` as the first line in your while loop. Then reference `currentLine` instead of `BF.nextLine()`.